# Need more info to debug data update

Tags: debugging, pivot-table, cakephp-3.0

I'm having some trouble editing an object through a pivot table and having a hard time debugging the problem. Every time I press the "Save"-button I'm getting smashed with the "Unable to update your product"-error, but no context.

I did look at the SQL Log in the CakePHP Debug Kit, but only find SELECT and no UPDATE-statements. I have a feeling that the data is already overwritten.

Is there a better way to debug these kinds of issues in my controller?:

```
public function edit($slug) {
    $product = $this->Producten
        ->findBySlug($slug)
        ->contain(['Categorieen', 'Winkels'])
        ->firstOrFail();

    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Producten->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Producten->save($product)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your product has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        debug($product);       --> dump below
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your product.'));
    }
    $this->set('product', $product);

    $categorieen = $this->Producten->Categorieen->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'categorieid', 
        'valueField' => 'type'
    ]);     
    $this->set('categorieen', $categorieen);

    $winkels = $this->Producten->Winkels->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'winkel_id', 
        'valueField' => 'naam'
    ]);    
    $this->set('winkels', $winkels);

}
```

**debug dump**

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'idproducten' => (int) 1,
    'merk' => 'Xiaomi',
    'model' => 'Mi Electric',
    'topsnelheid' => (int) 25,
    'bereik' => (int) 30,
    'gewicht' => (float) 12.2,
    'max_belasting' => (float) 99,
    'uitneembare_batterij' => false,
    'beschrijving' => 'stuff...',
    'categorie_id' => (int) 1,
    'thumbnail' => '',
    'afbeelding' => '',
    'tech_spec_url' => '',
    'slug' => 'xiaomi-mi-electric',
    'aangemaakt' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2018-12-20T22:03:49+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'aangepast' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2018-12-20T22:04:24+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'winkels' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Winkel) {

            '_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                'winkel_id' => (int) 1,
                'url' => 'test',
                'prijs' => (float) 0.99,
                '[new]' => true,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'winkel_id' => true,
                    'url' => true,
                    'prijs' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'ProductenWinkels'

            },
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'naam' => true,
                'winkel_url' => true,
                'logo' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [
                'logo' => [
                    '_required' => 'This field is required'
                ]
            ],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Winkels'

        }
    ],
    'categorieen' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

        'categorieid' => (int) 1,
        'type' => 'step',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Categorieen'

    },
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'winkels' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [
        'winkels' => []
    ],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Producten'
```

Comment: Start with inspecting `$product` after the `save()` call, it may contain error info.

Comment: The `debug($product);` right after `save()` did not get triggered. It did get triggered just before `$this->Flash->error`. Is there a way to get the SQL error displayed in the error message?

Comment: I didn't mean "right after" as in "inside the if block", just after the call ran, as that is when possible validation/rule errors will be available on the entity ;) SQL errors would trigger a hard exception, so unless you experience that, I don't think there are any SQL errors. What does the debug result looks like?

Comment: I've added the debug info. I am able to edit the product object if I do not edit the info of the pivot table.

Comment: Check the `errors` key, [**the `logos` field is required**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#requiring-field-presence) and probably missing in your request data. If you want that field to be optional, then you need to change the tables validation rules accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Errors key in the `debug()` dump says it all.